# Praw Discord.py Embed

Tags: embed, python-3.7, discord.py, praw

I need help converting this code into an embed, my problem is that it wont let me use the "submission.url" as a url for an embed. Help would be very much appreciated.
Side note: I have deleted all of the information that regards reddit so that it is not stolen.

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='',
                     client_secret='',
                     user_agent='')

@bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('AnimalMemes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)
    
    await ctx.send(submission.title)
    await ctx.send(submission.url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use (f"words{sumbission.url}")

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of an embedded command;

```
@bot.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    sub_submissions = reddit.subreddit('AnimalMemes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 20)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in sub_submissions if not x.stickied)
    e = discord.Embed(title=f'Requested by {ctx.author}', description=f'{submission.title}', color=0xFFFFF)
    e.set_image(url=submission.url)
 
    await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Comment: Of course you can modify this to your likings.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured this out as well but I also have transitioned to aiohttp as it is much faster for use on Discord.